# How to apply a user defined function to a range of values in KQL

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

I have a function that outputs a table:

```
let my_function = (InputDate: datetime){....}
```

What I would like to do is apply this function on a range and combine the result as in:

```
range date_X from ago(7d) to now() step 1d
| project my_function (date_X)
```

Any ideas? I tried many things but ended up with only code errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function should take a table as a parameter, then you can use "invoke" to call it. Here is an example from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions#invoking-a-user-defined-function)

```
let MyFilter = (T:(x:long), v:long) {
  T | where x >= v
};
MyFilter((range x from 1 to 10 step 1), 9)
```